# How can I generate c/c++ code from matlab simulink block using 'Build Model' function?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink

I have a controller block designed in Matlab R2013b simulink. I want to generate a c/c++ code of the block by using the 'Build Model' function. However, I keep getting this error:

*"An installed compiler was not detected. Certain simulation modes, as well as host-based coder builds require that a compiler be installed. Please install one of the supported compilers for this release as listed at:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/win64.html
MATLAB must be restarted after the compiler is installed*."

I  downloaded Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (supported and Compatible Compilers – Release 2013b). However I am still getting the same error.

Please can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio have you got installed?

Comment: Run `mex -setup` and select the appropriate compiler.

Comment: @TimBergel, I have visual studio 2005 Remote degubber. However, I use codeblocks for my c/c++ development

Comment: @EsuabomDavidDijemeni Neither visual studio 2005 or codeblocks appears to be in the list of supported compilers in the link you posted in your question. And a remote debugger is not a compiler of course. So I think you need a different compiler, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TimBergel I see your point. Sorry my bad. I am using GNU GCC Compiler. Do you think I should change my compiler to Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 ?

Comment: @EsuabomDavidDijemeni Not a problem! Yes, MS VC++ 2010 is on the list, but it specifies the Professional version which is going to be costly if you do not have it already. Best of luck

Comment: If you downloaded the SDK and ran `mex -setup` you should be able to pick your compiler.  Did you try that?  What did it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1- download the  Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 from http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2012a/win64.html.

Step 2 - Open the command line and type mex -setup

Step 3 - type y to locate installed compilers

Step 4 - Type the number in front of the Microsoft Software Development Kit  7.1 (for me it was 1)

Step 5 - type y to verify your choice

Step 6 - Open matlab and use the 'Build Function' to convert your simulink block to c/c++ code (For me it worked)